# Can't figure out how to extract data from excel-to-txt file

Tags: java, csv, file-io, text-files

I had an excel file containing data I had to use. For the purposes of a project, I converted it to .txt since we are required to use .txt, not .xlsx. I'm not sure what to use as a separator so that I can read data cell wise. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXsP6.png)
I can't use a space because the 'supervisor name' has spaces in the name. I'm using FileIO in Java.

I used a scanner object to read each line in the file and it worked but I can't figure out how to read each individual cell.

I would appreciate advice on how to handle this in a csv file too.

Comment: `FileIO` isn't a thing, at least, not in the core libraries. More generally, trying to read this data in directly is severely underestimating how complex this can get; use a [CSVReader](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-csv-file-java-using-opencsv/).

Comment: a separator ? Maybe use `\t`, TAB character.